# Animation transition effect need to be reduce on hover

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to create animation, where on hover i am changing image from default image to hover image.

I am using CSS3 animation and keyframe properties,

CSS

```
.fader img {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.fader img:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fader:hover img:first-child {
  animation: toggle 2s infinite alternate 2s;
}
.fader:hover img:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: toggle 2s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes toggle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="fader">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/000000" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/FFFFFF" />
</div>
```

I have created [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mayankbhadauria/uadsxxm6/) for the same

This is working fine , I need to do little change.

when one image change to next it leaves impression of the last one.
I am looking for the transition without footprint of last.

As given in [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mayankbhadauria/uadsxxm6/) , before black image comes, white image get slowly fade out then black comes, same happen from black to white. I want change without fade out effect.

I have tried

```
animation-timing-function: linear, ease, ease-in, ease-out, ease-in-out
```

but that doesn't work,

also i reduced delay time

```
animation-delay: .5s
```

but still that doesn't work. any idea ?

Comment: I think you expect something which it doesn't exists x). It's the normal behaviour to have grey between black and white. Maybe I don't get it what you need.

Comment: if i replace black and white with images, it leave with fadeout effect .its not about gray between black and white. I want to get next image without fade out transition in between. I hope it will explain

Comment: You just need a normal hover ?

Comment: @RémyTeats , no i have animate back and forth from default to hover image until i am hovering.